# Display all records that contain specific field.

Tags: combobox, record, ms-access-2013

I have a combobox with different project names. Projects might have more than 1 record belonging to them (so more than 1 record has a field with the same project name). I want to display all the records belonging to the project selected in the combobox.

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly...

SELECT [Project Name], [Supplier], [Number of Tools], [Total cost]
FROM Quotations
WHERE [Project Name] = [Forms]![Quotations]![Combo0];